# android download image port 69

Tags: android, ip-camera

there is an IP camera and I want to download a snapshot image.
this is the url : `http://test:11223344!!@85.105.152.138:69/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/2/picture`
as you can see; port is 69 not 80

this is my code:

```
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imgSnap);
    new DownloadImageTask(img).execute("http://test:11223344!!@85.105.152.138:69/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/2/picture");

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap webImage = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            webImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return webImage;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I got FileNotFoundException. but I think the reason is port 69.
How can I get the image?

Comment: try to load this URL in `WebView`, it should load there. number of port may be the problem just like plenty of other things, like [`http` instead of `https`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) (define `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`)

Comment: also note that this URL isn't pointing strictly on image, it needs log-in (`test:11223344!!@`). browers may do that automatically, but simple `InputStream` is desired only to stream data, may not handle log-in feature